Comments on the book Topology by James Dugundji
This post asks for comments on the book "Topology" by James Dugundji.
Before I was given a copy of this book, I never read it in detail. When I did, I think this is a very good book. However, it seems very few instructors use this book in these years, as there are other alternatives, for example, the books by Munkres and Armstrong, and perhaps some newer books. If I were an instructor teaching a course on general topology and some algebraic topology, I  would use Dugundji's book as the textbook.
What I want to know is comment or even criticism on Dugundji's book, probably by some seasoned mathematicians. Besides there are newer books and Dugundji's book is hard to get a copy, are there any other reasons that you would choose other books on topology?

The book of Dugundji has several errors, at least in the proofs. Some of them appeared here on MSE.

@Ulli Thanks, I see. Is there an errata for Dugundji's book?

Not that I know of. But perhaps you will find one?

@Ulli I googled but nothing comes up. I feel that this book does not belong to the internet era.

I used it and I liked it very much.

@Ulli I doubt that you find books without errors.
